# How to get a zip of the npm mysql package that is installed globally?

Tags: npm, aws-lambda

I am a beginner and i am currently making a chat bot using amazon lambda and i need to upload that npm-mysql package as a zip in AWS lambda, so that i can use it.So how to create a zip of this npm-mysql package that is installed globally in my system and where can i find the npm-mysql package in my system for zipping it?

Answer (score 0):

Dont install the package globally.
A good practice is to create your own `package.json` and then zip up your code + the node modules.
What this would look like is something like this:

```
<project-folder>
   |
   |--index.js (Your code)
   |--package.json (this has details including the packages your use)
   |--node_modules
          |-- This contains all the modules you need
```

Once you have this structure you can just zip this up and upload to lambda.A
You can create the `package.json` file using `npm init` and filling in the details.
For dependencies do a `npm install <dep_name> --save` will start adding these deps to `package.json`.